# Multiple Quaternion Multiplication C++

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have multiple quaternions that would be represented in the following Euler-Angle format:

```
glm::vec3 VecA(10,20,30); //InZeroRot
glm::vec3 VecA(1,1,1); //InTrackingRotation
glm::vec3 VecA(2,2,2); //InJoystickRotation

glm::quat OutRotation = InZeroRot * InTrackingRotation * InJoystickRotation;
```

But i am running into issues as from what i have researched Quaternions are not commutative.
How would i be able to rotate all 3 of these Quaternions along one-axis (if that's even the right thing to do?).

My goal is to be able to apply multiple rotations and acheive the following result for this example being: (13,23,33).

Comment: You will not achieve that result, and you don't want to. You need to clearly define the relationship between your rotations and apply them in order.

Comment: Also, what order and frame are the Euler angles in?

Comment: My euler angles are in the order x,y,z in degrees, For my use i am wanting to apply multiple rotations to a camera. One being set from the ui and/or another being set by a tracker.
As one use case is the tracker having 90 degrees of yaw and when i apply any pitch to the joystickrotation it will instead roll. But i have no control over the order as the use could use both.

Comment: See [Conversion between quaternions and Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) The following looks good as well [A Tutorial on Euler Angles and Quaternions](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/sites/sci-tea.benari/files/uploads/softwareAndLearningMaterials/quaternion-tutorial-2-0-1.pdf)

Comment: I'm not trying to convert from euler to quaternion, in this side of my application im only dealing with Quaternions. The Euler-Angles in the question was just some example angles to show an expected output. Thanks!

Comment: You are saying "I want to apply these rotations and end up in this position". But geometry doesn't work this way. You either apply rotations in order and end up in whatever position they bring you to, or calculate your rotations from your current position and your desired position.